# Connecting to the GUI (xorg Server) via SSH connection to an "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS" V-Server machine from ionos.de

Tags: ssh, xorg, gui, xserver, vps

I got a server from Ionos.de with Ubuntu 20.02.2 LTS.
The Ubuntu was already pre-installed. After the server was set up by the provider, I connected to the server using the console provided on the website (KVM-Konsole). I saw it boot up. The GUI was not loaded.  After the normal update/upgrade procedure (apt get update/upgrade), I typed startX. It came the message that it is not installed. So I installed it. For this I typed: `sudo apt get install xserver`

Then I got the message that I should select a package.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package xserver is a virtual package provided by:
  xvfb:i386 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  xvfb 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  xnest 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  xserver-xephyr 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2
  tightvncserver 1.3.10-0ubuntu5
  tigervnc-standalone-server 1.10.1+dfsg-3
  xserver-xorg 1:7.7+19ubuntu14
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

then I tried two different packages:

`xserver-org`
und
`xvfb`

If I then enter ``startx'', the following occurs:

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.9
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-140-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 02:35:03 UTC 2021 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 ro apparmor=0
Build Date: 08 April 2021  12:29:22PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.2~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jul 12 22:10:52 2021
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I preferably access the server with a GUI using **MobaXterm** or another program and log in as root/user?

What should I do next to in case this was a total wrong way?

And the Purpose for all this is to use it as Linux system with an thin GUI I can connect to with my iPad or any other device. I want to test some things with this attempt. Its important that i So I really need a GUI on this specific server. It doesen't matter how light weight this GUI is.

Thank you for any tips!

E

Comment: An X Server is not a complete Desktop Environment (DE). Try a real lightweight DE (`sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`). Then your X Server has something to serve.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to install / launch X *clients* on the remote server, and display them locally on MobaXterm's X server

Comment: @steeldriver Yes.

Comment: So maybe you should make sure the `x11-apps` package is installed on the server, then try something like `xclock` or `xeyes`. If the mobaXterm server is enabled properly configured, it should display on your local screen.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you so far. I installed the x11-apps and **lubuntu-deslktop** with GDM on the server . Also ```sudo apt-get install -y x11-apps``` 
also typed ```apt-get install xauth xfonts-base```
the ```xclock```worked and the other also. But when I type in ```startx``` I get this:

Comment: I left out the beginnig output

[...]
```Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jul 14 18:23:13 2021
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
VMware: No 3D enabled (0, Success).
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: So I checked the LOG File and I get in /var/log/Xorg.0.log : ```(EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied```

Comment: *What does it mean?* I dont get any smarter from this... can somebody please help?!

Comment: anyone could help me?